# Python / Tkinter fails when classes are calling each other's methods

Tags: python-2.7, tkinter

I'm on to programming a graphical frontend in Python 2.7.3 using Tkinter. I've got a main menu (A in the example) and a window (B). A contains a listbox, B is doing something which needs the content of the listbox in A. After B has finished its work, I need a method in A (doSomething) called. My simplified code looks like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import Tkinter as tk

class A(object):
    def __init__(self, root):
        self.__mainMenu = root
        self.__LB = tk.Listbox(self.__mainMenu)
        self.__LB.pack()
        self.__LB.insert(tk.END, "foo")
        b = B(self.__mainMenu, self.__LB)

    def doSomething(self):
            print "Ham and spam!"

class B(object):
    def __init__(self, mainMenu, LB):
        self.__mainMenu = mainMenu
        self.__LB = LB
        print self.__LB.get(0)
        self.__mainMenu.doSomething()

def main():
    root = tk.Tk()
    gui = A(root)
    root.mainloop()

main()
```

The following output is produced:

```
$ ./myTest.py 
foo
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./myTest.py", line 29, in <module>
    main()
  File "./myTest.py", line 26, in main
    gui = A(root)
  File "./myTest.py", line 11, in __init__
    b = B(self.__mainMenu, self.__LB)
  File "./myTest.py", line 21, in __init__
    self.__mainMenu.doSomething()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk/Tkinter.py", line 1767, in __getattr__
    return getattr(self.tk, attr)
AttributeError: doSomething
```

Where does this error come from? Why is the error output so poor?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I always use gtk (no experience with Tk), but from what I see, you invoke doSomething method of root, not of A class, in B.**init**.__mainMenu.doSomething()
Invoke B with self in A init:

```
b = B(self, self.__LB)
```

Comment: I'm so ashamed... It was late at night! :-) Thanks, that solved it.